# selection of image map links jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am new to Jquery need to get some thing like image mapping
[image: selected image]

> 1. Had 2 images selected  and unselected .And on top of this selected image having 3 images for (facebook,linkedin,email) and when user selected on the particular portion of the selected image suppose if on facebook then it should redirect to that link).

how to redirect  to that particular link can anyone guide me how to do so?

```
<div class='opt-slider-person selected opt-slider-cont' data-id="1">
    <div id="team">
        <ul>
            <li class="facebook">
              <a href="https://www.twitter.com" 
                 target="_blank" title="facebook"></a>
           </li>
            <li class="linkedin">
              <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" 
                 target="_blank" title="linkedin"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="email">
             <a href="mailto:?subject=News&amp;" 
                target="_blank" title="email"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='opt-slider-person opt-slider-cont' data-id="2"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(".opt-slider-person").click(function () {
     $(".opt-slider-person").removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');
```

### });

edited: basically i have a div something like this below,
and i want to add 3 more links in every div starting from data-id="1".
something like which i mentioned above.and these links should only appear when i click on data-id ="1" not in the other id's.How i can able to do this?

```
<div class="opt-slider">
                <div class="inner">

                  <div class='opt-slider-person selected opt-slider-cont' data-id="1"> </div>
                  <div class='opt-slider-person opt-slider-cont' data-id="2"> </div>
                  <div class='opt-slider-person opt-slider-cont' data-id="3"> </div>
                  <div class='opt-slider-person opt-slider-cont' data-id="4"> </div>
                  <div class='opt-slider-person opt-slider-cont' data-id="5"> </div>
                  <div class='opt-slider-person opt-slider-cont' data-id="6"> </div>
                  <div class='opt-slider-person opt-slider-cont' data-id="7"> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

and below css :-

```
<style>
.opt-slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 190px;
    margin: 0;
}
.opt-slider .inner {
    position: absolute;
    height: 190px;
    left: 0;
}
.opt-slider-cont {
    float: left;
}
.opt-slider-person {
    widtH: 200px;
    height: 188px;
    background-image: url(../../Content/images/team_unselected.png);
}
.opt-slider-person.selected {
    background-image: url(../../Content/images/team_selected.png);
}

.opt-slider-person.selected a
{
    position: absolute;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            text-indent: -1000em;
}
```

based on the below code tried to modified :

```
$('.opt-slider-person').filter(function () {   // Selects list of elements
        $(this).data("id") === 1;                 // Filters elements by data-id
    }).click(function () {                         // Binds an event listener
        $(this).parent()                          // Selects siblings and itself...
       .children()                        // by selecting children of parent
       .html('<div id="team"><ul><li class="facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" title="facebook"></a></li><li class="linkedin"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank" title="linkedin"></a></li><li class="email"><a href="mailto:?subject=News&amp;" target="_blank" title="email"></a></li></ul></div>');   // Inserts the links
    });
```

Comment: where is opt-person-text class in html?

Comment: @JqueryKing: opt-person-text is not required i removed it.

Comment: Are you mixing select/click/hover? It's not clear enough what you want to happen to the links when they're hovered over/clicked.

Comment: Would you mind making the question a bit more clear? We have no idea what you are trying to do. What specifically do you want to happen? Don't be afraid to make it a few sentences long.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist: edited with more information.

Comment: So you're trying to add links inside the opt-slider-person class elements when you click on the first one?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist yes i am trying to add links inside the opt-slider-person class elements when i click on the first one like wise for other ones too.and based on your comments i added the below code but could able to make the link work.

Comment: What didn't work? Be specific. Did you get errors?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist: i am not sure whether i doing was correct i added just like what you mentioned but while clicking it's not taking the links, i am adding above what i am doing please do correct me if anything is wrong in the script.Also is it possible to check .data("id") == 1 instead of selected div??if so how to implement for checking??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58656/discussion-between-theenvironmentalist-and-reapen).

Answer (score 0):

Here are your steps:

1. Trigger on the click event
2. Add links

Try something like this:

```
$('.opt-slider-person').filter(function() {   // Selects list of elements
    $(this).data("id") === 1;                 // Filters elements by data-id
}).click(function() {                         // Binds an event listener
    $(this).parent()                          // Selects siblings and itself...
           .children()                        // by selecting children of parent
           .html(/* link code goes here*/);   // Inserts the links
});
```

If I'm not understanding what you're asking, feel free to let me know so I can update the answer.